# Computing all spanning trees of an undirected, regular grid (lattice)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Say we have an undirected regular grid (e.g., a lattice) made of `15x15` nodes. I have come across the [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula), which states that the number of possible spanning trees in a graph is a function of the number of nodes:

`n^(n-2)`

My questions:

1. Is this applicable to grids straight away?
2. What are its limitations?
3. Is there any universal formula for computing this number for all kinds of graphs (Erdős–Rényi, Barabasi–Albert, Watts–Strogatz, and so forth), or is this something that needs a different approach - perhaps a brute-force one?

Comment: Cayley's formula deals with trees connecting a given set of labeled nodes in an arbitrary way. But if you are given some graph together with all its edges, finding a spanning tree means selecting some of the given edges such that certain conditions are met. All in all: We are talking about completely different problems here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Cayley's theorem tells us the number of spanning trees in $K_n$, the complete graph on $n$ vertices, is equal to $n^{n-2}$. Another way of viewing this is that there are $n^{n-2}$ trees on $n$ labeled nodes. So, in short, Cayley's theorem applies only to the number of spanning trees in $K_n$ and not in a general graph $G$.

But surprisingly enough, there is a way of computing all the spanning trees of a graph $G$! [Kirchhoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) states that the number of spanning trees of G is equal to any cofactor of the Laplacian matrix of G. This is one of my favorite results in spectral graph theory.

So I haven't worked out the exact answer to your question about the number of spanning trees in a grid graph yet, but you have all the tools to do it. First, derive what the Laplacian matrix of a general grid graph will be, then compute any cofactor of that matrix. Please let me know if you want more help or hints to this end.

Finally, you asked about random graphs such as Erdős–Rényi and others. As I stated above, Kirchhoff's Theorem holds for any arbitrary graph $G$ so you could apply it to any single instance of a random graph, but you might be more interested in the *average number of spanning trees* for a random graph model. In this case, you could compute any co-factor of the expected Laplacian matrix of your random graph to obtain your result.

Comment: @CF84 Kirchoff's theorem gives you the number of spanning trees in a graph $G$. It doesn't tell you anything about the number of minimal spanning trees. I believe it's true that if all edge weights are unique, then there is a unique minimal spanning tree. I don't know of a slick way to compute the number of minimal spanning trees in a graph. Perhaps start with a minimal spanning tree via Kruskal's Algorithm and for each edge in the tree, look for an edge in the graph with the same weight and see if the change of edges results in a tree.

Answer (score 4):

There actually is a formula for the number of spanning trees - the so called [Kirchhoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem).

For a graph $G$ let $D(G)-A(G)$ have eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$. Here $A(G)$  is the adjacency matrix of $G$ and $D(G)$ is the diagonal matrix having the respective degrees of vertices of $G$ on the diagonal. Then the number of spanning trees of $G$ is $$ (\lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_n)/n\,.$$

In particular if $G$ is the complete graph $(n-1)I - J + I = -J-I$ has eigenvalues $0, n,\ldots, n$ and so Cayley formula follows.

The grid graph $G_{n,m}$ is the so called Cartesian product of two paths on $n$ and $m$ vertices - $P_{n} \square P_{m}$

The eigenvalues of $D(G \square H) - A(G \square H)$ are known to be $$\lambda_i + \mu_j \quad \mbox{for } i = 1,\ldots, \quad \mbox{and} \quad j = 1, \ldots, m,$$ where $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_j$ are the eigenvalues of $G$ and $H$ respectively.

Hence if you want to compute the number of spanning trees of the grid graph you need to figure out the respective eigenvalues for the path graph. These are well known to be $$1 - \cos{\frac{\pi k}{n-1}} \quad \mbox{for} \quad i = 0,\ldots, n-1\,.$$

I guess its now a tirsome task to derive a formula for the number of spanning trees of grid graphs.